# Chrome Extension img.onload function continuously executes

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, onload

I'm writing a Chrome extension that blocks possibly offensive content. One method that I am implementing is to scan all the images and see how much skin is showing. I create a new image object, set the crossOrigin flag to " ", then make a onload function that will draw the image onto the canvas, read the data from the canvas, and then perform the analysis, setting a boolean flag for the calling function. After defining the onload function, I assign a src to my image node from my list of sources from the webpage.
The image_scanner function is called inside of a for loop that is looping through each image node on the webpage and performing various operations to block on. This is the last operation that I perform. Here is the code that calls image_scanner:

```
                if (image_scanner(options.scanner_sensitivity, images[i]))
                {
               // Replace the image with a blank white image
               images[i].src = chrome.extension.getURL("replacement.png");


                }
```

Here is the image_scanner function

```
    function image_scanner(sensitivity, image)
    {
       // Sensitivity is a number and image is an image node.

      // Declare a variable to count the number of skin pixels
      var skin_count = 0;

      if (image.width == 0 && image.height ==0)
      {
       // This means the image has no size and we cannot block it.
       return false;
      } // end if


      var return_value = null; // set bool flag
      // Create an HTML5 canvas object.
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

      //window.alert("Created Canvas."); // used for testing.

      // Get the context for the canvas.
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // This is what we actually use to draw images and pull the data from them.

      context.canvas.width = image.width; // Set the canvas width to the width of the image
      context.canvas.height = image.height; // Set the canvas height to the height of the image


      img = new Image(); // Create a new image node to circumvent cross-domain restrictions.
      img.crossOrigin = " "; // Set crossOrigin flag to ' ' so we can extract data from it.

      img.onload = function(){
          window.alert(img.src); // This always gives the same src until Chrome ends the function
          context.drawImage(this, 0,0); // Draw the image onto the canvas.

          var pixels = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data;


          // Now pixels is an array where every four entries in the array is the RGBa for a single pixel.
          // So pixels[0] is the R value for the first pixel, pixels[1] is the G value for the first pixel,
          // pixels[2] is the B value for the first pixel, and pixels[3] is the a (alpha or transparency) value for the first pixel.

          // This means that pixels.length/4 is the number of pixels in the image.
          // Now we calculate the number of skin pixels we can have before blocking the image.
          var limit = ((pixels.length)/4) * (sensitivity/100);

          // Now we go through the array of pixel data, checking if each pixel is a skin colored pixel based on its RGB value (the first 3 entries for that pixel in the pixels array)
          // Each time we find a skin colored pixel, we increment skin_count and check if skin_count >= limit. If so, we return true.
          for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) // We go up by four since every four entries describes 1 pixel
          {

           // pixel is skin if 0 <= (R-G)/(R+G)  <= .5  and B/(R+G) <= .5 pixels[i] is the R value, pixels[i+1] is the G value, and pixels[i+2] is the B value.
           if ((0 <= ((pixels[i] - pixels[i+1])/(pixels[i] + pixels[i+1]))) && (((pixels[i] - pixels[i+1])/(pixels[i] + pixels[i+1])) <= 0.5) && ((pixels[i+2]/(pixels[i] + pixels[i+1])) <= 0.5))
           {
               skin_count++;
               //window.alert("Found skin pixel."); // used for testing.

               if (skin_count >= limit)
               {
                   //window.alert("Blocking image with src: " + image.src); // used for testing.
                   img.onload = null; // try to clear the onload function
                   return_value = true;
                   return false;
               } // end inner if
           } // end outer if
          } // end for loop

       //var temp;
       img.onload = null;
       return_value = false;
       return false;

      }; // end onload function


   img.src = image.src; // Set the new image to the same url as the old one.    



   return return_value;
} // end image_scanner
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but the onload function will run, go through the pixels, set the flag, return, and then run again. I've tried debugging in Chrome's debugger, and that's all I could find. I've tried setting the onload to null inside of the onload function, but it doesn't work. I've tried returning false from the onload function. I've tried waiting in the image_scanner function until return_value != null, but that just seemed to enter an infinite loop and I never even got the alert from the onload function. If anyone has any idea why the onload function will repeatedly execute, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to set `.src` to the blank image and don't want `.onload` to get called again when that loads, then you should clear `.onload` before you set `.src`.

```
if (image_scanner(options.scanner_sensitivity, images[i])) {
    // clear our onload handler
    images[i].onload = function() {};
    // Replace the image with a blank white image
    images[i].src = chrome.extension.getURL("replacement.png");
}
```

It also looks like you're returning a value from the `onload` handler and expecting that value to get returned from the image_scanner function.  It doesn't work that way.  The onload handler gets called some significant time later, long after `image_scanner` has already returned.  You will need to rewrite your code to work with the asynchronous handling of `onload`.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. If you notice, the function image_scanner is called in the if statement, as it returns a bool. It is inside of image_scanner that I create a new image object, and give it the onload function that is repeating.

Comment: @DragonSlayer - See the second issue I added to my answer.  `onload` is asynchronous (called long after image_scanner()` returns so you can't use it synchronously like you are trying to do.

Comment: What if I put a bool flag in the onload handler, and then put a while loop after that would do nothing until the bool flag was set by the onload handler?

Comment: @DragonSlayer - you can't loop like that in javascript.  No other code can run while looping so your flag cannot get set while looping.  You have to convert your code to work with asynchronous events.

Comment: Ok. And you think that will solve the problem of the onload function continuously re-executing? I was thinking about it, and it occurred to me that it might be because by the time the onload listener fires, the img object has been destroyed because the function returned. Does that make sense?